# Solve $2x^{3}ydy+(1-y^{2})((xy)^{2}+y^{2}-1)dx=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is to solve this

$$2x^{3}ydy+(1-y^{2})(x^2y^{2}+y^{2}-1)dx=0$$

What I tried was to bring this equation in linear differential equation form but failed. I have also tried out rewriting the given in such a way so that each term can be integrated easily but to no avail it isnt exact either since $\frac{dm}{dy}$ is $4y-4y^{3}$ and  $\frac{dn}{dx}$ is $6x^2y$

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the parentheses around the whole equation?

Comment: By mistake sorry...

Comment: @almagest By mistake edited now....

Comment: You should not be able to get a linear form, those $y^2$ terms will be a problem. Nor is the equation separable. Have you checked whether it is exact?

Comment: @Ian No i havent checked that....

Comment: @Ian No it isnt....

Comment: Perhaps write out the two partial derivatives that you used to check that, so that we might find an obvious integrating factor.

Comment: Try substituting $y(x) = \sqrt{1-v(x)}$ and rearranging to get a Bernoulli equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to get the Mathematica solution. Just chipping away at it,
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(y^2-1)}{x^3}(x^2y^2+y^2-1)$$
Let $s=y^2$. Then
$$\frac{ds}{dx}=\frac{(s-1)}{x^3}(x^2s+s-1)$$
Let $s-1=t$. Then
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac t{x^3}(x^2(t+1)+t)$$
Let $t=\frac1u$. Then
$$-\frac1{u^2}\frac{du}{dx}=\frac1{ux^3}\left(x^2\left(\frac1u+1\right)+\frac1u\right)$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}+\frac1xu=-\frac1x-\frac1{x^3}$$
The integrating factor is
$$\mu=e^{\int\frac1xdx}=e^{\ln x}=x$$
So
$$\frac d{dx}\left(xu\right)=x\frac{du}{dx}+u=x\left(-\frac1x-\frac1{x^3}\right)=-1-\frac1{x^2}$$
$$xu=-x+\frac1x+C=\frac xt$$
$$t=\frac x{-x+\frac1x+C}=\frac{x^2}{-x^2+1+Cx}=s-1$$
$$s=\frac{1+Cx}{-x^2+1+Cx}=y^2$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+Cx}{-x^2+1+Cx}}$$
OK, I take it back. That is the Mathematica solution. I found my mistake while typing this up.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica gives the solution as

$$ y(x) = - \sqrt {\frac{ 2 c x -1 } { 2 c x + x^2 -1 } } $$

If you use the sub $z = y^2$,you'll find the equation transform  to

$$ x^3 d z + ( 1-z) ( x^2 z + z -1) dx =0 $$
Then it looks like you should be able to find an integrating factor in $z$.